# How can I modify command line in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-10.04

I am using a vpn service from certain server. I was given with a root account, and when I connect with a root account, the command line looks like below.

root@xa9g82:/etc/#

Then I used useradd to add an account called 'temp'
When I connected to the server with temp, then the command line only has a single character.

$

The user information is not shown, neither the path. Also, note that, in root's command line I can use tab to automatically complete the filename, however 'temp's command line inserts tab space, when I press tab. It is very inconvenient.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually edit ~/.bashrc. Being root, you might want to change the system-wide preferences, at  /etc/bash.bashrc. Personally, I changed some lines in ~/.bashrc to look like:-

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
##    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"  # default
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h: \W\a\]$PS1"  # How I like it
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

use prompt to set the prompt.... (man prompt...)

it depends on what shell you run each one has it's own tricks, but you can make it looks as you wish.

[BASH](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html)

[TCSH](http://www.tcsh.org/PromptExamples)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the default shell for root is set to /bin/sh, which does not provide many of the features that you may used to if you use a shell like bash. To check if this is the case, run the following command:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep ^root
```

The last component of the line that this command outputs will be your shell (which, as stated previously, I'm guessing is /bin/sh). If this is not the shell you want (it probably isn't), then edit /etc/passwd (using nano or whatever editor you're most comfortable with) and change your shell to something more palatable, like /bin/bash. After doing this, you'll need to log out and then log back in.